# Iterator pattern - How adding or removing elements from an aggregate can you end up accessing an element twice or missing it completely?

Tags: iterator

How adding or removing elements from an aggregate can you end up accessing an element twice or missing it completely ?

The GoF Design Patterns mentions this under the Iterator pattern : 
*"if elements are added or deleted from an aggregate you might end up accessing an element twice or missing it completely"*

I cannot think of a use case when this could happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example.  Imagine you are iterating over an array-like collection.  An iterator might keep track of your current index in the list.

```
        *
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

In this example, if you insert an element to the front of the list while iterating, the index will now be pointing to an element that has already been seen.

```
        *
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Similarly, if you delete an element, the index will now skip an element.

```
        *
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```